# GridView.RowCommand Event

Tags: vb.net, gridview

In the first column of a `Gridview` I am trying to place an image button that executes its own routine and opens another `webform`.
I understand that this should be arranged via an click-event, so I did search for examples the inet  for solutions.

I found  this in the books:

> GridView.RowCommand Event Occurs when a button is clicked in a
>   GridView control.

The next code generate an error:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" 
     rowSelection="single"
     AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="OID" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
   ForeColor ="#333333"   BorderColor="#CC9966" rderStyle="None"            
BorderWidth="1px">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
<Columns>
<asp:ButtonField 
          commandname="Select" 
           ButtonType="Image" 
          ImageUrl  ="~/Props/Pen.png"   
onrowcommand="Pen_Click()"
            />
```

**Error:**

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' does not have a public property named 'onrowcommand'.
```

many regars, 
Ton from Thailand

Answer (score 0):

The `onrowcommand` belongs to the GridView itselt not the button.

```
<asp:gridview id="ContactsGridView" 
    onrowcommand="ContactsGridView_RowCommand"
              runat="server">
```